# Maximum number of columns in edit form in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, max, edit

I have a list which is having around 75 columns in it. The edit form of this page is customized using sharepoint designer and 70 columns are visible there. Now the task is to add 30 more columns in the edit page. I added all those columns in list but when I edited the edit form to include the 30 columns after a point the webpart is showing the error.

**"Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator."**

I commented the field I added, then page is rendering in browser. I want to know is there is any limit to the edit form? if yes, how much is that.

If you need any more information, pls ask.

Comment: I ran into this today, but with only 65 fields. In my tests it seems to not have anything to do with the number of fields, but instead the number of nodes in the template. You can test this by adding empty rows until the page fails to load.

Answer (score 0):

A hot fix is available from Microsoft to resolve this issue. You need to log a call with them and ask for sharepointfoundation2010-kb2597136-fullfile-x64-glb.exe.
After installing it, use the below Powershell script to make the changes to the Timeout value. Changing it to 2 seconds worked.

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$farm.XsltTransformTimeOut = 5
$farm.Update()
```

Comment: Thnaks Prachi. I am waiting for the event log from client. I also read about this issue earlier. Before requesting for a hot fix, I need to make sure that this is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround for this is setting the "AllowPersonalization" property of the Web Part Zone to true. This error occurs when the "AllowPersonalization" property of the Web Part Zone is set to false and a user with less privilege tries to access the zone. This leads to the WebPartPageUsageException. This could be overcome by just setting the AllowPersonalization property to true.